# How to open mime attachments in external apps from iPhone 5S iOS 7 mail, and the best app to use

Tags: email, ios

How do I open mime attachments from external apps from iPhone 5S iOS 7 mail? Which apps would be the most efficient to use?

Answer (score 1):

Forward the message to yourself INCLUDING the attachment.  It works for me.

Comment: I know this is a five-year-old question/answer, but here's a couple of Apple Discussions threads from around that time, corroborating the "forward it to yourself" technique as a valid workaround. {[Thread 1](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5376194?answerId=24446532022#24446532022)} {[Thread 2](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5448523?answerId=24336872022#24336872022)}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a (fairly brutal) [Apple Shortcut that can open a MIME attachment](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/b45c19958e2d4144b53e57841c5a2bee) in Apple Mail in iOS 14. If you don’t trust the shortcut link and would like to build it yourself, I’ve included a screenshot of the steps. Note that the `Previewing` step must be changed to `File as Text` (tap on `File` there to do this).

[image: Screenshot of Shortcut setup]

Comment: What are the two Documents steps for, can't you just use Previewing to show the input directly?

Comment: I did try that approach but couldn't make it work, even with `File as Text`. The two steps create a temporary text file. There's a third document step at the end which deletes it. Would be great if you know of a simpler way that works!